# Is there any relation between batchfile vs batch job?

Tags: windows, batch

Here's what I think I know:

Batchfile is the filetype of shell scripts in Windows.

A batch job is not interactive, you start it and then watch it do its business but it doesn't check in with you.

Am I wrong about these things? I can understand why a batch job is called what it is, but why is a windows shell script called batchfile?

Comment: A “batch file” is the file that contains the batch script. A “batch job” refers to a batch file that has been run.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file the word batch in batchfile refers to batch processing

Comment: Batch job is a very generic term used in computer science pre-dating the batch file.  We used this term before DOS even existed.  It means that you are going to do a bunch of stuff without interaction (see @Gantendo batch processing).  *Usually* via script (witch *might be* a batch file).  *Usually* (when most use it), it will be a scheduled task but it didn't always mean this.

Answer (score -1):

**Batch file** is just a `.cmd` or `.bat` file.

**Batch job** is a special **login type** in windows. It is used when you run app using **windows task scheduler**: https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/book/page.aspx?spid=chapter3